# How to force layered source code structure in Delphi

Tags: delphi

In our organisation we would like to force layered structure of source code. Each unit would be in certain "level" and units would be able to use only units in same or lower level.

Example:

Suppose we have these units: `L1_A.pas`, `L1_B.pas`, `L2_C.pas`, `L2_D.pas`, `L3_E.pas` (`LX_` means "level X").

`L1_A` and `L1_B` can use each other. `L2_C` and `L2_D` can use all `L1_*` units and each other. `L3_E` can use all other units.

If `L1_*` unit tried to use either `L2_*` unit or `L3_*` unit, we need to abort compilation and produce some error ("Unit in lower level tried to use unit in higher level").

Have we coded in C (or other language with preprocessor), we would for example define `LEVEL_1`, `LEVEL_2`, `LEVEL_3` constants and in all 1st (resp. 2nd) level units check if eihter `LEVEL_2` or `LEVEL_3` (resp. `LEVEL_3`) constants were defined in which case we would emit relevant error.

Delphi defines (defined by `{$DEFINE}`) don't have effect outside unit in which they were defined. Named constants and constant expressions can be used outside, but which one we see depends on the order of units in `uses` (ie if `L1_A` defines `const Level=1` and `L2_C` `const Level=2` and `L1_B` contains `using L2_C, L1_A` than `Level` in `L1_B` would be `2`).

I came up only with naming convention [`LX_Unit.pas` (or LX.Unit.pas), where `X` is level and `Unit` is "real" unit name], and checking with a script in `svn` commit hook.

We would like to use only basic Delphi (no external tools).

Comment: See [IF directive](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IF_directive_(Delphi))

Comment: I don't know if you have any building pipeline, or something that can run testing/linting tools in your process, but I'd think it would be easier to have something in that process look for discrepancies. Otherwise you'd need every L2 unit to expose something, and every L1 unit needs to check the presence of that something. Still doable, of cource, especially since you could use the include directive for that, but still..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

But you can check for constants. It doesn't matter if several units define the same one, and what their type or value is, as long as its name matches a certain pattern. In a way, such a constant is like an "exported" `$define`:

```
const
  Level3 = 3;
```

- Unit X has constant Level1
- Unit Y has constant Level3
- Unit Z has constant Level3

```delphi
 uses
   X, Y, Z; // Z.Level3 hides Y.Level3, but that doesn't matter.

 {$IF declared(Level3)}
```

---

As the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IF_directive_(Delphi)) states:

> **Declared** returns **True** if the argument passed to it is a valid declared Delphi identifier visible within the current scope.

Comment: Hmm, `declared` had passed me by.  +1

Comment: @MartynA: Very useful for cross-platform: `{$IF declared(AnsiString)}` or versioning: `{$IF declared(UnicodeString)}`.

Answer (score 6):

Like Rudy said, you can use normal constants for that, and repeat them in each unit.

Note that units can be included in the interface section as well as the implementation section. Including a level 3 unit in the *implementation* section of a level 2 unit, doesn't bring the level 3 constant in scope of the level 2 unit's *interface* section. For that reason, to be completely safe, you'd need to set the constant in the interface section (to expose it in the first place), and check for the constants in the implementation section.

I would put at least the check, and maybe the constant as well, in included files. In each unit, you can include the file for that level.

So every level 1 unit would contain, in its implementation section, after the uses clause:

```
{$include level1check.inc}
```

In that file, you can do the check, and let the compiler bail using a fairly elegant FATAL message directive. level1check.inc would then look something like this:

```
{$IF Declared(level2)}
  {$MESSAGE FATAL 'Cannot include a level 2 unit in a level 1 unit'}
{$ENDIF}
{$IF Declared(level3)}
  {$MESSAGE FATAL 'Cannot include a level 3 unit in a level 1 unit'}
{$ENDIF}
```

I wonder though, what is keeping a developer from cheating? If they can modify the uses clause, they can also remove or circumvent the check. It's something that you may want to enforce in your build pipeline, but if you're doing that, maybe there are more elegant ways of checking this, for instance, by simply getting the level1, level2 and level3 unit names, and scanning the uses clauses of each level1 and level2 unit for illegal units.

Comment: The developer can (nearly) always cheat of course. You have to assume that they will follow company policy. I guess what the OP is trying to avoid is accidental (or through laziness) failure to follow standards.

Answer (score 5):

In L1*.pas include

```
CONST Level1 = TRUE;
```

Then in other units use

```
{$IF Declared(Level1) }
```

or

```
{$IF NOT Declared(Level1) }
```

etc.

You can probably figure out the rest from there :-)